# How to load php instantly from ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to directly load a page using ajax. Here are the details:

HTML:

```
<div id="feedback"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'do.php',
        success: function(data){
            $('#feedback').html(data);
    });
});
```

do.php:

```
<?php
    //Do whatever...
    echo "Done!";
?>
```

What I am seeing is: the page first loads, and there is a delay before the "feedback" div gets written. How can I solve this?

Comment: $(document).ready(...) means that it wait until the page loads. And then it of course take some time to do the request.

Comment: dont surround with `$(document).ready(...)` part, it will then run the moment those lines are "read"

Comment: the request is sent after dom is ready so that will take a little time to get you the response.

Comment: It will never load "instantly", you should change your html->php to include "do.php"

Comment: Nothing happens without latency.  You haven't told us enough about your current setup to really understand where your latency comes from. How much time is spent in initial page load?  How much time is taken in making the AJAX call?  How much of that time is spent in different server-side processes?  How much time does it take for external resources specified by the injected HTML to load?

Comment: uhhhhhmmmmm why on earth are you doing your initial loading using xhr. That is pretty ... horrific

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Just to be clear, I know that the delay is because of the do.php as it is doing quite a bit of things(not all code is there). I don't mind that delay, but I don't want the page to show first and then suddenly "Done" is written. What I want is for the page to wait until the php request is finished and then load the whole page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know of course it will have that delay. Suppose your page containing `<div id="feedback">[…]</div>` is loaded at 0th second now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'do.php',
        success: function(data){
            $('#feedback').html(data);
    });
});
```

Is called as apparently it’s visible when document loads. So suppose its called at 3rd second when the document is ready—you can refer [to this page](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for details—now you will be seeing that `feedback` div blank for 3 seconds.

I can suggest 2 things:

1. You can place a loader image by default inside the div so your code will change to `<div id="feedback"><img src='loader.gif'></div>` (Assume you have the `loader.gif` in the same directory of the page). By doing this you will make the user visually understand that some processing  is going on and will load data.
2. Instead if you can place `file_get_contents()` or `include()` so it will look something like this `<div id="feedback"><?php file_get_contents('do.php');?></div>` or `<div id="feedback"><?php include('do.php');?></div>` As far as I know `file_get_contents` will execute the page and then load while include will load and then execute hence in include() you have the variables in the page available whereas in `file_get_contents` are not available but CSS would work in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could start loading immediately and then add the data when everything has completed.

```
var _data = null;
var _ready = false;

$.ajax({
    url: 'do.php',
    success: function(data){
        _data = data;
        tryAddData();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    _ready = true;
    tryAddData();
});

function tryAddData(){
     if(_ready && _data !== null){
         $('#feedback').html(_data);
     }
}
```